# Excel: Return value based on lowest score

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a database that collects profits from different stores on a weekly basis:

[Database Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmO0w.png)

Each week, I need to show which store had the lowest profit in each state.

[Output Needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI2aw.png)

I'd need to show the name of the site, and also what its profit was for that week.

Could anyone help me? Thank you :)

Comment: 1) Copy your sample data into question (as a text) and format it (as it is a code); 2) Show desired result (data, not form only) on that source data. 3) And what you want to obtain if 2 or more sites provide the same minimal profit?

Answer (score 1):

Good Day Anniesoptera,

Assuming I understand your question right I would solve accomplish this with a combination of 3 Excel formulas. MIN, INDEX & MATCH.

1. Sort the data by state
2. Assuming your information is in cells A1-C14, use the =MIN formula to 
   determine which the lowest profit for the state is.
     So for California (MIN(C2:C5)
3. Use this formula in the MATCH Formula 
    (MATCH((MIN(22:C5),C2:5,0). This will give the row which this figure is in
4. Add this formula to the INDEX Formula to obtain your site 
   =INDEX(A2:C5,(MATCH((MIN(C2:C5)),C2:C5,0)),1).

   This can then be done again to obtain the amount change the final value in the formula 
   from a 1 to 3 (The column number). 
   =INDEX(A2:C5,(MATCH((MIN(C2:C5)),C2:C5,0)),3)

[image: Screen Cap of the spreadsheet with a complete formula]

I hope this helps.